# Prove that $f(z) = e^z$ maps $\mathbb{C} \setminus B $ onto $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

Prove that $f(z) = e^z$ maps $\mathbb{C} \setminus B $ onto $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ where $B$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

I have no idea how to even attempt this question so I would greatly appreciate some hints.

Comment: Note that $e^z$ has period $2\pi \mathrm{i}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16909/

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

What is the image of the exponential function as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?

What is the image under $f$ of a closed vertical line segment in $\mathbb C$ of height $2\pi$?

Comment: The image of $f(w)$ where $w$ is of the form $x+ 2i\pi$ would be $e^{x}$.

Comment: @user372834 : The image of the real line is $f(\mathbb R) = (0,\infty)$. And the image of the segment from $x+iy$ to $x+i(y+2\pi)$ is the circle $\{z\in\mathbb C: |z|=e^x\}$. You should now be able to prove the assertion, considering that there is a closed horizontal strip $S_B$ of height $2\pi$ lying outside of any given bounded set $B$ (note that such a strip is the union of segments of the form I mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+yi$ and $w=u+iv=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ ($\rho>0$). Assume that $e^z=w$ and then
$$ e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) $$
from which one has
$$ e^x\cos y=\rho\cos\theta, e^x\sin y=\rho\sin \theta. $$
Thus
$$ x=\frac12\ln\rho,y=\theta+2n\pi, n\in Z.$$ 
So for any $w=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, one always can choose $n\in Z$ such that
$z=\ln\rho+i(\theta+2n\pi)\in\mathbb{C}\setminus B$; namely $f(z)=e^z$ is from $\mathbb{C}\setminus B$ onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Is $x = \frac{1}{2} \ln \rho$ correct or is it meant to be $x = \ln \rho$

Comment: @user372834, it is $x=\ln\rho$.